# Use custom msbuild toolset with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Creating a custom toolset via these instructions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/standard-and-custom-toolset-configurations?view=vs-2019) works fine when launching msbuild directly but not through Visual Studio.

Is it possible to redirect Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 to use a custom msbuild toolset?

Comment: From the document you can find something like `By defining entries in the registry, you can specify computer-wide Toolsets that apply to MSBuild.exe, Visual Studio, and all hosts of MSBuild.`, maybe that's what you need, but the document didn't state how to register them, for this you can send feedback to author  by the button in the bottom of the page. Also, what your custom toolset do? If it just import some targets and some properties, maybe you can try [Directory.Build.props](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) to achieve same goal.

Comment: Thanks @LanceLi-MSFT, the custom toolset is simply a version of msbuild that we want to pin our teams to. I'll look into both of your suggestions.

Comment: Any update feel free to share here.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT  - I reached out to the author of the article, but no luck yet. The problem I have is that after creating a custom toolset in the msbuild.exe.config file, it never seems to be able to find it. In the build log, I see: 'Project file contains ToolsVersion="MyCustomToolset". This toolset may be unknown or missing...'. I know that I'm modifying the correct exe.config file, if I change the 'Current' toolset, it lets me know. This is when building from VS 16.2.1.

Comment: The only time I can actually use a different toolset is if I explicitly pass it into msbuild.exe via the -tv arg. Otherwise, in VS or msbuild, it gives me the above error (uknown or missing) when using the ToolsVersion attribute.